# How to access the columns of a table in django

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a form with 2 fields, Output name and column name. Output name stores the name of the output table. On selection of the output table, I want to list all the columns in the selected table. I know how to create the drop down dependency, I just want to know how to access the column names in the table

models.py

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
  # this is the name of the table to be accessed
  Outputname = models.OnetoOneField(Output)

  column_name = # what do i do here? #
```

EDIT:
The output table has certain column headers, which I want to access. That's what I mean by column names.

Comment: what do you mean access column name?

Comment: Output name stores the name of the table. So each table contains certain header columns which I want to access. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: I can't understand clearly yet.. what exactly you want to save in one object? you want to add column name for each `Output` object?

Comment: Output name is the name of a table being stored in the database. The table has header columns and then data entries underneath each column. I want to access those headers. The table is completely dynamic so there's no way of knowing the headers beforehand.

Comment: which means you want to directly get table column name from database?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally understand your question after few comments.

You don't have to save column name to your `Model`. django automatically create table name using `app` and `model` name. `<app_name_lowercase>_<model_name_lowercase>`

If you want to customize it, just add `class Meta` like below

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
  # this is the name of the table to be accessed
  Outputname = models.OnetoOneField(Output)

  class Meta:
      db_table = 'my_table_name'
```

[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#db-table), you can see more detail about `db_table` option and `Meta` fields. (I usually use django defailt table name)

Also, just look django model docs ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/)) for glance of django model. django ORM is very powerful so you don't have to do much about sql.